# form not submitting on localhost or remote

Tags: html, forms

After submitting the form nothing happens, page doesn't reloads. Out of ideas.

```
<form action="/departmentinsert.php" method="POST"  class="contact-form">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Отделение" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
                    Добавить <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>                
</form>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What's `departmentinsert.php` doing?

Comment: There is an insert sql statement on the page. But the issue is that on clicking submit button, page is not refreshing for further action.

Comment: When looking at the browser's log, if your browser actually sending an HTTP POST? On the server-side, do you have full errors turned on?

Comment: code formatting

Answer (score 0):

to submit the form you will need to use `<input type="submit">` instead of the `<button>` tag

once you update the code I am sure it will work, if you are using PHP it should be like this

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
 // your code
}
?>
```

if this doesn't work please post your PHP as well so i can check where's the problem

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I changed formatting to  and it works now. My code now is

```
<form action="" method="POST" >
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-group" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Отделение" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-group" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Заголовок" type="text" size="255">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <input class="form-group" id="breadcrumb" name="breadcrumb" placeholder="Хлебные крошки" type="text" size="255">
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                      <input class="form-group" id="pagetitle" name="pagetitle" placeholder="Титул страницы" type="text" size="255">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    Опубликовать?
                                    <input name="active" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                                    </div>
                               <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
                                        Добавить <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                </form>
```